# Does the Shadow Magic sorcerer's Hound of Ill Omen stack disadvantage if I summon more than one?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer

I just became a level 6 [Shadow Magic sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#ShadowMagic) (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 50-51). At 6th level, shadow sorcerers gain the Hound of Ill Omen feature:

> At 6th level, you gain the ability to call forth a howling creature of darkness to harass your foes. As a bonus action, you can spend 3 sorcery points to magically summon a hound of ill omen to target one creature you can see within 120 feet of you. The hound uses the [dire wolf](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/dire-wolf) statistics, with the following changes:
>
> - The hound is size Medium, not Large, and it counts as a monstrosity,
>   not a beast.
> - It appears with a number of temporary hit points equal to half your
>   sorcerer level.
> - It can move through other creatures and objects as if they were
>   difficult terrain. The hound takes 5 force damage if it ends its turn
>   inside an object.
> - At the start of its turn, the hound automatically knows its target’s
>   location. If the target was hidden, it is no longer hidden from the
>   hound.
>
> The hound appears in an unoccupied space of your choice within 30 feet of the target. Roll initiative for the hound. On its turn, it can move only toward its target by the most direct route, and it can use its action only to attack its target. The hound can make opportunity attacks, but only against its target. Additionally, while the hound is within 5 feet of the target, the target has disadvantage on saving throws against any spell you cast. The hound disappears if it is reduced to 0 hit points, if its target is reduced to 0 hit points, or after 5 minutes.

It doesn't say a limit to how many I can summon. Does this mean I can stack disadvantage on a target?

Comment: What do you mean by "stack disadvantage on a target"?

Answer (score 12):

## Disadvantage does not stack, under any circumstances

From PHB p. 173 (or the basic rules), specifically the section on [Advantage/Disadvantage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AdvantageandDisadvantage):

> If multiple situations affect a roll and each one grants advantage or imposes disadvantage on it, you don't roll more than one additional d20. If two favorable situations grant advantage, for example, you still roll only one additional d20.

While you are correct in observing that no rule stops you from summoning two (or more) hounds to fight a creature at the same time, the disadvantage would only ever apply once to that specific creature. The only way to get two disadvantage effects with this ability is if you target multiple creatures; each targeted creature would get Disadvantage for the duration on its saving throws against spells you cast.

Answer (score 3):

## No

A common misconception about Advantage/Disadvantage is that it stacks in a sort of "contest" against each other.  RAW, it does not.

Only one "Advantage" is considered, no matter how many are possible for that situation.  Only one "Disadvantage" is considered in the same way.  So if you're blinded and prone, but someone is helping you, it nets your attack to just be a standard roll, even though there are more "disadvantages" against your roll.